# What are the defaults values for @property in iOS?

Tags: ios, properties

What are the defaults values for @property in iOS ?

For example, if I declare @property NSString* photographer;

is the default value (assign) or (retain) or what else ?

(atomic, non-atomic) ?

I cannot find this information from the documentation.
thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the defaults are `(atomic, assign)`, however, you should not leave them empty.

The default may change at any point, and you're writing code that is relying on the definition of the property.

For example, if you rely on the default `assign` and it changes to `retain` for whatever reason in the future, then all of your code is going to leak.

Conversely, if the default is retain and you rely on that and it changes to assign, then your code is going to crash when you inevitably over release an object.

Do not rely on any default, regardless of what they may be.

Explicitly define your properties' attributes.

Comment: Beware: the default with ARC has changed to `strong`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773604/property-definitions-with-arc-is-strong-default-now).

Comment: Precisely what I said in my answer: the defaults may change. Don't rely on them. Be Specific.

Comment: Unfortunately the Apple headers *very* frequently use the defaults so it's still quite useful to know what they are.  See CAShapeLayer.h for a prime example.

Comment: Knowing what they are is fine, but my point still stands that you shouldn't write your own properties without specifying their semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are atomic by default so that synthesized accessors provide robust access to properties in a multithreaded environment—that is, the value returned from the getter or set via the setter is always fully retrieved or set regardless of what other threads are executing concurrently.

If you specify strong, copy, or retain and do not specify nonatomic, then in a reference-counted environment, a synthesized get accessor for an object property uses a lock and retains and autoreleases the returned value.

I don't think Apple will change it in the future, but unfortunately the most common is non atomic, so you may have to write it down.