# @property definitions with ARC: Is strong default now?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Just running the ARC refactoring tool on the new xcode 4.3.1 and noticed that my (nonatomic, retain) properties are being swapped out for just (nonatomic) instead of (nonatomic, strong) like in the previous xcode.

My code seems to run fine after this change so I am assuming that it is defaulting to strong anyway, anyone know why things have changed with the ARC converter?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, `strong` is the default in Xcode 4.3 and later. It's documented both in the [LLVM docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) and in Apple's guides to [using properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30) and [working with ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4).

Comment: An Apple engineer confirmed this to me in a TSI. This was changed for consistency within ARC. Both warnings and documentation are wrong and will be fixed.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property now documents this change.

Comment: nschum's URL doesn't quite take you to the right section anymore, but I've edited the correct documentation URL into the answer.

Comment: What will happen if I declare primitive data type property with just `@property (nonatomic) int value`? Will it automatically be treated as `assign`?

Comment: ARC only applies to properties (and variables) of object types. Property ownership qualifiers only apply to object types. Properties of primitive type are effectively `assign` whether you declare them as such or not.

Comment: it seems in 7.1.1 that strong is no longer default or implied.

Comment: @Augie How does it seem that way? Given that I haven't heard about thousands of ARC-based apps crashing since 7.1.1 came out, I suspect this hasn't changed.

Comment: it could be an isolated event in one of my apps, but out of many user devices and iOS versions, only iPhone 5s running 7.1.1 had a bug where collection views inside table view cells were being lost.  The table view did not scroll, so this wasn't a dequeuing event. Adding strong fixed it.  It's a weird issue only for 5s 7.1.1.  Possibly the bug is actually with the table/collection view content retainment.

Comment: Might be worth asking a separate question about.

Answer (score 0):

When the property is a basic type, the default value is assign, when the property is a object type, the default value is strong