# @property assign

Tags: objective-c, ios

If "assign" is the default, can I leave it blank and it will make it assign?

```
@property BOOL sample;
```

What if I have defined the atomicity of it and then left it blank?

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sample;
```

Comment: in XCode 4.3 {strong} is the default, it was changed for ARC consistency. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773604/property-definitions-with-arc-is-strong-default-now

Comment: But then it's giving "strong" to my primitives? That's not possible.

Comment: A property of retainable object pointer type which is synthesized without a source of ownership has the ownership of its associated instance variable, if it already exists; otherwise, [beginning Apple 3.1, LLVM 3.1] its ownership is implicitly strong. Prior to this revision, it was ill-formed to synthesize such a property.

Comment: @JustinAmberson make that an answer so I can accept and give you credit!

Comment: @JustinAmberson That might be true for object pointers, but not for primitives. Primitives can't be retained or released. The default for all primitives is `assign`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the defaults are used if not otherwise specified.  However, it is good practice to be explicit in property definitions.  It is easier for a third party to understand what is going on, and/or know what should be going on.  Also, implementation details might change in the future.

Comment: In XCode 4.3 {strong} is the default for properties.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right:

```
@property BOOL sample;
```

is the equivalent of:

```
@property (atomic, assign) BOOL sample;
```

But of course, atomic isn't an attribute that exists so don't use it :)